Is there anyway to disallow accessing local network devices through global IPv6 addresses in linux?
I realize that this question might sound kind of strange, but it is necessary for my situation as far as I can tell.
The root of it is that my ISP assigns IPv6 global addresses dynamically and refreshes the assignment once in a while. I'm running a VM that I don't want accessing my local network. Everything works fine, I'm blocking all sorts of stuff, like local addresses as destination IPs for example. It's not a bad network sandbox, apart from this glaring hole in the security. The VM (assuming it knows the public IPv6 of one of my local network devices) can just communicate with them. This is because the host system has no way of telling proper internet addresses apart from local network devices that happen to be addressed using global IPv6 addresses.
Like I said, I can't setup any static prefix exclusion rules in my firewall because the prefix changes. And I want to stay away from changing the firewall rules with some sort of script that gets fired when the interface receives a new global IPv6. That's pretty disgusting, among other reasons because it allows for a certain small time window when the new IPv6 gets assigned where the firewall rules haven't been updated yet where the VM can access the local network devices without getting blocked. That's not good.
I was really hoping that there's simply some sysconfig variable somewhere that tells the linux kernel to not route any packets where the destination address prefix is the same as the interface global address prefix. Effectively like saying "You're not allowed to access local network devices through their global addresses".
I can't solve my problem by adjusting the firewall on my local network's router, because it isn't nearly configurable enough. Also, I'd prefer to keep my security contained to the host computer, so that I can move the computer to different networks without too much reconfiguration in the router and so forth.
Anyway, yeah, that's my situation. I'm really hoping someone can just point me in the direction of a simple fix, but I fear that there isn't one. Anyone got any good ideas on how to deal with this?

What's the real problem you are trying to address though? Why should the "neighbors" be treated differently? Just because they are "close to you"?

@TomYan Sorry I didn't get back to you. I've been busy. I don't appreciate the fact that your first instinct is to assume that I'm a victim of the XY problem, but I guess that's just the way it is on Stack Exchange sites. Anyway, as I said in the post, I'm running a VM. The whole point is to sandbox it, but still allow it internet access. I want to separate it from my local network though and only allow connections to the internet. The problem is that I've got no good way to block accesses to the global IPv6 addresses of local net devices because I can't differentiate them from internet addrs.

@NikTedig Clarification: Of course I can differentiate them from internet addresses, because I can filter based on the IPv6 prefix. But like I said that changes every so often and I don't see a good way to dynamically change the firewall rules without leaving time gaps in the security. I'm currently writing a kernel module which will do this for me, although I'm happy to abort that if someone can tell me how to accomplish it with iptables (accomplish it properly that is, I don't want any bash script nonsense, that doesn't work, like I said in the post).

You know what, I am not even sure whether what I was thinking about was "XYProblem", and I don't appreciate being despised of for having any first instinct anyway. The problem is, while you may consider a prefix or even a few non-contiguous addresses "special" because it is covered by a direct route or whatever reason, there is no ground for anyone else to consider so, let alone a knob for you to specifically forbid them from being possible destinations. Besides, the idea to "sandbox" with a knob inside the sandbox is at least technically silly and pointless.

FWIW, if your VM is in the same broadcast domain as your LAN, you'll need to filter at L2 anyway (like ebtables or an nft bridge table). L3 firewall on your router (or the hypervisor) won't even matter, even if it is configurable and the prefix is static. Also, don't forget about link-local addresses. While I am indeed not familiar if things have changed in the IPv6 ecosystem, probably what you really need is VLAN (with L3 filtering to forbid communications between the VLANs).

@TomYan "despised" is an exaggeration, my comment wasn't meant with the malice that I think you read from it, sadly that doesn't come across super well over text sometimes. In any case, I believe we can still be friends :) As for your technical points: The knob isn't inside the VM, it would be in the host in this scenario. Also, the VM isn't in the same domain as the LAN. Right now, I've got it NATed behind the host. Also, just because these "special" addresses are personal doesn't mean they don't deserve to be handled.

@NikTedig Additionally, I can imagine quite a few people having a similar situation, because "amateur" setups frequently have to deal with things like dynamic address assignment. That's what made me think maybe there's a pre-built solution for it. Yes, it isn't technically super general, but it's a conceivably common problem, so I don't think it was unreasonable of me to ask. Edit: I just remembered you also asked about link-locals. Those are easy enough to block. I've got those covered in my iptables setup.
